# How to update the datagridview after adding some data?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I just want to ask on how to refresh a datagridview. everytime i add some data, the data from the datagridview is repeating? thank you in advance. :D

Comment: How are you adding data?

Comment: Sounds like your not clearing the datagridview before re-adding the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a binding source, like this:

```
Dim TheBindingSource As New BindingSource() 
TheBindingSource.DataSource = GetDataFromSomewhere()
DataGridView1.DataSource = TheBindingSource
TheBindingSource.ResetBindings(False)
```

Now when your data needs to be refreshed, you create a new binding source and call `ResetBindings()` again, like this:

```
Dim TheNewBindingSource As New BindingSource()
TheNewBindingSource.DataSource = GetDataFromSomewhere()
DataGridView1.DataSource = TheNewBindingSource
TheNewBindingSource.ResetBindings(False)
```

The `ResetBindings()` method takes `True` if the schema of the data has changed and `False` if only the values of the data have changed.

Read [BindingSource.ResetBindings Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.resetbindings.aspx) for more information.